# Getting an exception (Store fault access) after returning from ISR by mret in E21 RISCV processor

Tags: exception, cpu, interrupt, riscv

While executing **mret** instruction while returning from an interrupt, the very next write operation CPU does causing an exception with ***excode as 7*** (store access fault).

Then mstats.MPP value changes to **00** (user mode). Though, processor previously was into machine mode. This is fine as per RISCV specs. I've configured interrupt into CLIC vectored mode.

I cannot find a reason why CPU land into the exception. But, If I forcibly change the value of mstatus.MPP to machine before doing any write operation, things work just fine. There is no exception with this case. This behavior is an unexpected.

I'll appreciate some pointers to fix this issue!!

Comment: Some more insights would be very helpful in finding out the problem. Like are you running a baremetal/rtos program intended only to run in M mode only or is it a RTOS or GPOS that intends to run its kernel in M mode and applications in user mode. 

If its a baremetal application or even a RTOS that intends to run only in M mode then most probably you haven't initialized mstatus csr properly. You need to set MPP bits to 11 in boot time architecture specific configuration.

Comment: Hello, I'm also having this issue. Any help would be appreciated.